# Navigating plists and settings objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have a resource file (plist) added to my project. I am currently coding some sort of a "helper" for reading and writing to it. I have 3 get and 3 set methods. First one returns an object at the top, second one returns object which is inside of another dictionary (see code) and the third one returns an object at any given depth I just have to specify the node names so it can get there. (I hope you can understand me)

The problem comes with setters. Setting an "surface" object is no big deal so is setting an object that is in another dictionary. The problem comes when I try to set an object at a depth.
Before I write anything else I will post the code so you can understand what I'm saying.

fullContent is a `NSMutableDictionary` containing the file.

```
//This one is easy, just return the object for the key.
- (id)getSurfaceObjectForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    return [fullContent objectForKey:key];
}

//Hope you understand this one. Main parent is a string with the name of the first node. It gets a dictionary out of my plist and returns an object for key (I have a dictionary structured plist)
- (id)getMainParentChildObjectForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSAssert(!mainParent, @"Main parent must not be nil");

    return [[fullContent objectForKey:mainParent] objectForKey:key];
}

//This one gets the element at any given depth I just have to pass in an array containing node names
- (id)getObjectForKey:(NSString *)key atDepthWithChildren:(NSArray *)children
{
    id depthElement = fullContent;

    for (int i = 0; i < children.count; i++)
        depthElement = [depthElement objectForKey:[children objectAtIndex:i]];

    return [depthElement objectForKey:key];
}

//Sets a top (surface) object
- (void)setSurfaceObject:(id)object ForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [fullContent setObject:object forKey:key];
    [self writePlistContent];
}

//Sets an object inside a dictionary (mainParent - string with the name of dictionary node)
- (void)setMainParentChildObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [[fullContent objectForKey:mainParent] setObject:object forKey:key];
    [self writePlistContent]; //Self explanatory. I write this to file
}

//This is where my problem comes. How do I save this to plist without making any other changes to it? Im guessing I have to rebuild it from inside up?
- (void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key atDepthWithChildren:(NSArray *)children
{
    id depthElement = fullContent;

    for (int i = 0; i < children.count; i++)
        depthElement = [depthElement objectForKey:[children objectAtIndex:i]];

    [depthElement setObject:object forKey:key]; //I set the desired object but I dont know how to save it

    for (int i = 0; i < children.count - 1; i++)
    {
        //Here i guess i would have to build the NSDictionary from inside out. Using a NSMutable array perhaps?
    }
}
```

I hope you understand my problem. I hope Im not complicating things too much. Im just really tired and have been up for nearly 24 hours now and cant think of a way to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't just use your:

```
[self writePlistContent];
```

to save it.

Surely it will save the entire contents of the plist.

Comment: writePlistContent overwrites the whole plist with content of `NSMutableDictionary *fullContent`.

Comment: Yes indeed it is. But I want to change something in fullContent with that last method but I dont know how. Look at the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - it happens - but it looks like you set your depthElement to fullContent -> drill down into the full content (in the for loop) -> set the object in the correct NSMutableDictionary -> now the tree represented by your fullContent should be correct and you just have to write the whole thing to flash using writePlistContent. What am I missing?

Comment: I am copying fullContent to depthElement and then overwrite it with the new dictionary (depthElement = [depthElement object...]) at the end I get to the one I want to be and replace it. So I have a NSDictionary in depthElement which is only a part of the solution now right? I need to se the depthElement to fullContent at one level higher I guess?

Comment: After you have set the element you want, you don't care about depthElement. It is fullContent that you care about and it should be correct and ready for writing.

Comment: Woot! Its working o.O Would you mind explaining this to me? How can fullContent get modified when im only changing depthElement? Is this because depthElement is a pointer to full content?

Comment: It's because fullContent has children, the children have children, and their children have children and so on. All the children, grandchildren and great children can be reached by traversing the tree that has its root at fullContent. Not sure if that is clear... Full content is the root of a tree and when you navigate down through it and change a part, it is all still connected to the same tree with full content as the root.

Comment: Yes in understand. But I am modifying depthElement and not fullContent. depthElement is a copy of fullContent.

Comment: No, depthElement and fullContent are pointers to the same memory location after `id depthElement = fullContent;`

Comment: Ok got it. This was missing :) Thank you very much!